# Can I remove parts of an Assetbundle at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a lot of fbx files that I converted into Assetbundles. Some of them contain a camera that I want to remove/ignore when I am placing that at runtime. Is it possible to to that? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

When "placing" at runtime I assume you instantiate them. They will then be [`GameObjects`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html), which you can edit through code. If your GameObject has a Camera GameObject as Child you can use `transform.Find("GOName")` to find the camera gameObject, and then [`Oject.Destroy()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) it or just deactivate it.

However, this is bad practice as it requires names to stay the same without breaking the code. You should really only save assets exactly as you need them. If your asset doesnt need a camera, it should not have one attached. You should take that little time to clean up your assets, because it will eliminate a lot of time consuming future problems.

Comment: Will try this. Luckily, the Name is always "Camera" as these are auto-generated fbx files. I wont be able to create them without camera though